# PHP How to use for loop's variable with mysql_fetch_array to indicate row to get data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have trouble to use for loop's variable `$counter` with

```
$HA_Row = mysql_fetch_array($HA_Res);
```

to indicate which row's data I am going to get. Basically, I have no idea to use `$counter` and `$HA_Res` together.

I want to it can display different rows' data of my database.

For example, like

```
echo "$HA_Row[Check_In_Date]"
```

I have tried

```
echo "$HA_Row[$counter][Check_In_Date]"
```

and

```
echo "$HA_Row[Check_In_Date][$counter]", echo "[$counter]$HA_Row[Check_In_Date]"
```

but none of them works.

Thank you so much! Appreciate your time.

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['Hotel_User_ID']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Hotel_Info WHERE Hotel_ID =".$_SESSION['Hotel_User_ID']);
    $userRow = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $HA_Res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Hotel_Account WHERE Hotel_ID =".$_SESSION['Hotel_User_ID']);
    $HA_Row = mysql_fetch_array($HA_Res);
    $HA_Count = mysql_num_rows($HA_Res);

    // echo "$HA_Count". "<br>";
    // echo "$HA_Row[Check_In_Date]";

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hello - <?php echo $userRow['Hotel_Email']; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
    <div id="left">
    <label>Welcome <?php echo $userRow['Hotel_Uname']; ?> </label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="content">
            <a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <a href="manage.php"> Manage </a> <br>
    <a href="home.php"> Update </a>

</div>
<div id="body">
    <center>
    <div id="Hotel-InfoForm">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<!--            <table.ver2 align="center" width="60%" border="0"> -->
            <table align="center" width="85%" border = "1">
                <tr>
                <th>Check In Data</th>
                <th>Check Out Data</th> 
                <th>Theme</th>  
                <th>Bed Size</th>       
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                for($counter = 0; $counter < $HA_Count; $counter = $counter + 1)
                {       

                    // using $counter for $HA_Row[....]

                    echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "$HA_Row[Check_In_Date]";
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "$HA_Row[Check_Out_Date]";
                    echo "</td>";

                    $Theme_Res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Theme WHERE Theme_ID = ".$HA_Row[Theme_ID]);
                    $Theme_Row = mysql_fetch_array($Theme_Res);

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "$Theme_Row[Theme_Name]";
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "$Theme_Row[Bed_Size]";
                    echo "</td>";

                    $Guest_Res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Guest_Info WHERE Guest_ID = ".$HA_Row[Guest_ID]);
                    $Guest_Row = mysql_fetch_array($Guest_Res);

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "$Guest_Row[First_Name]";
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "$Guest_Row[Last_Name]";
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "$Guest_Row[Gender]";
                    echo "</td>";

                    function ageCalculator($dob)
                    {
                        if(!empty($dob))
                        {
                            $birthdate = new DateTime($dob);
                            $today   = new DateTime('today');
                            $age = $birthdate->diff($today)->y;
                            return $age;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo ageCalculator($Guest_Row[Birth_Day]);
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "$Guest_Row[Phone_Num]";
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "$Guest_Row[Email]";
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "</tr>\n";

                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    </center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Loop the `fetch`. You probably could do a join on your two queries to just have one. You also should update your driver and use parameterized queries.

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Maybe you should get a developer to write the code for you, especially if this is going to be used for a real hotel booking system

Comment: I am just learning PHP. Thank you for your suggestions. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mysql_fetch_assoc and while looping, like this:

```
while($HA_Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($HA_Res)){
    echo $HA_Row[Check_In_Date]."<br>";
};
```

This while will loop in each instance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't normally use a counter to control `fetch`, especially if you just want to process the records in sequence. Each call to `fetch` will return the ***next*** row in the result set without further action on your part.

First, replace all your `mysql_*` calls with their `mysqli_*` counterparts. Then replace your line

```
for($counter = 0; $counter < $HA_Count; $counter = $counter + 1)
```

with

```
while ($HA_Row = mysqli_fetch_array($HA_Res))
```

On each loop, `mysqli_fetch_array` returns the *next* row, and after reading the last row the next call returns **`false`**, which exits the loop.

Switching to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` will also gain you prepared statements, which help to protect against [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1), among numerous other benefits.